# T-SQL ;WITH XMLNamespaces Across Multiple SELECT Statements

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, namespaces

I am trying to figure out how I can define an set of xmlnamespaces one time and then use them in multiple select statements

```
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES
    ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS x)

    SELECT... 
    [Code referencing namespace x]

    SELECT ...
    [Different code referencing namespace x]
```

Comment: You cannot do this - you need to re-define the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES...` before each `SELECT` statement ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XMLNAMESPACES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx) keyword is reserved in the context of the WITH clause.

So in a nutshell No you will need to use a WITH clause for each SELECT statement.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why that means the OP can't do what they're asking about

Comment: @DanField I made an update to the answer. thanks for the comment :)